# ubuntu server 12.10 get input signal out of range on HP DL380 G4

Tags: server, 12.10, graphics, hp

After installed ubuntu 12.10 server on HP DL380 G4, I can't boot into it. 
And the LCD got message "Input signal out of range, recommened settings is 1280x1024".

```
I can't see the terminal and tried several LCDs and still can not work either.

How can I should do now?

I tried 12.04 but got fail message when installing (select and install software).
```